# Sum hex from Node Buffer for 2's complement

Tags: javascript, buffer, checksum

I have a node buffer.

<Buffer 0a 80  04  06  20  ff  ff  ...

```
let buffTotal = 0;

for (const item of fileBuff) {
  console.log(item) 
  buffTotal = buffTotal + item;
}

console.log((~buffTotal + 1 >>> 0).toString(16))
```

I'm attempting to loop through the Buffer and add up all the hex values to calculate the single byte 2's complement, however I just get a very long hex string instead of a single byte representing the 2's complement sum of characters.

Comment: Why are you using the radix 16 in the toString? Can you post your actual buffer, and what you're expecting the byte to be?

Answer (score 1):

When you accumulate the sum of bytes in the buffer, you’re not ensuring that the result wraps around according to the rules of (modulo) arithmetic over the target integer type.  At the end of the loop, `buffTotal` is probably a large floating-point number that *approximates* the sum of all bytes in the file instead of a wrapped-around modulo sum.  When computing the sum, you should clamp it to the target integer type (which I assume is likely unsigned 8-bit).  To do that, you can modify your code as follows:

```
let buffTotal = 0;

for (const item of fileBuff) {
  console.log(item) 
  buffTotal = (buffTotal + item) & 0xff;
}
```

or more succinctly,

```
let buffTotal = fileBuff.reduce((a, b) => (a + b) & 0xff, 0);
```

You can then compute the two’s complement as

```
console.log((-buffTotal & 0xff).toString(16));
```